# React state becomes empty string using type='number' input

Tags: reactjs

I have an input component

```
<input  value={this.state.age} onChange={e=> {this.setState({age:e.target.value})} } type='number' />
```

That works fine when all of the characters are numbers, but when one, or more of the characters are minus sign, plus sign, or dot, the state automatically becomes an empty string, although it looks allright on the browser. It is the same in Chrome and Firefox. Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the number field only accepts -, 0-9 and e to be entered. As a workaround you could place the + in the HTML before the input like:

```
+ <input type="number" />
```

Why you have "one or more characters" in it? Could you give some examples?

Comment: I need an input that can accept more than one character, and the chracters could be numbers, the plus sign and the minus sign. I would like to know why react state breaks when the input contains a minus sign character.